# How do i use the regex in scala to check the first 3 chars of filename

Tags: regex, scala

What is the scala code to  check the first 3 characters of a fileName is String

I want a boolean to be returned , If the first 3 chars of a fileName are letters , then true needs to be returned , otherwise false

```
val fileName = "ABC1234.dat"
val regex = "[A-Z]*".r


val result = fileName.substring(0,3) match {

case regex(fileName) => true
case _ => false 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [findFirstIn](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findFirstIn(source:CharSequence):Option%5BString%5D) matching 3 times a char a-zA-Z `[A-Za-z]{3}` or use `\\p{L}{3}` to match any letter from any language and check for nonEmpty on the Option

```
val fileName = "ABC1234.dat"
val regex = "[A-Za-z]{3}".r

regex.findFirstIn(fileName).nonEmpty
```

Output

```
res0: Boolean = true
```

---

If you want to use substring with matches as in the comment, matches takes a string as the regex and has to match the whole pattern.

```
fileName.substring(0,3).matches("(?i)[a-z]{3}")
```

**Note** that substring will give an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the string is shorter than the specified indices, and using findFirstIn with the Option would return false.

Comment: OK sure, I  will try this , but i also tried the below code, It throws error as well
scala> fileName.substring(0,3).matches("(?i)[a-z]".r))
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
fileName.substring(0,3).matches("(?i)[a-z]".r))

Comment: fileName.substring(0,3).matches("(?i)[A-Za-z]{3}") worked form , Thanks for your answer also

Comment: @SurenderRaja The `matches` takes a string (without the `.r`) and it has to match the whole pattern like `fileName.substring(0,3).matches("(?i)[a-z]{3}")`

Comment: They added a `matches` method to `Regex` at some point https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#matches(source:CharSequence):Boolean